# Class setup for Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to setup a class for Gson to put my information into. Here is what the JSON being read looks like:

```
{
  "id": 1234,
  "name": "name"
}
```

I want to return the "id" part of the JSON, but I need Gson to put it into a class first, right? Here is how my class looks right now:

```
class getID
{
    private int id;

    public int getID()
    {
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

Here is how I'm trying to put the JSON into this class using Gson:

```
Gson reader = new Gson();
getID myID = reader.fromJson(inputLine, getID.class);
```

Here is where I'm getting the error:

```
System.out.println(myID.getID());
```

I don't have a good understanding of Gson, but I've used JSON before. Searching this topic I found a lot of information but never one that shows the this simple of JSON being sorted by Gson. Any help would is welcome.

EDIT:

The error is a null-pointer exception, pointing to the "System.out.println(myID.getID());" The inputLine is the return from an API request in JSON format. It's a one line that looks like {"id":1234,"name":"name"}

Comment: It'd be nice if you posted the error. It would also be nice if you told us what `inputLine` is.

Comment: also would be good to follow java conventions and do not confuse by gatId name os class :(

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with the code snippets you have posted; they would not produce any errors.

Comment: To expand; post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) - you may discover your problem as part of the exercise.

Comment: The error is a null-pointer exception, pointing to the "System.out.println(myID.getID());" The inputLine is the return from an API request in JSON format. It's a one line that looks like {"id":1234,"name":"name"}

Comment: Post the code that contains the Gson deserialization and the printing. `fromJson` cannot  return `null`.

Comment: You can edit your question to add more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `inputLine` is a `String` with the value `{"id":1234,"name":"name"}`, the following

```
reader.fromJson(inputLine, getID.class);
```

cannot return `null` and therefore that `myID` variable cannot be `null`.

You must be calling

```
System.out.println(myID.getID());
```

on a different `myID` variable.